# Individual character identification for cursive(?) script

Tags: character-identification

[image: Two pieces of paper with single characters; the left one likely reads "愛"]

Hi! I found these being used as bookmarks in my grandmother's old books. My mother said the left-hand character is most likely 愛, but couldn't read the right-hand one. Has anyone got an idea what it is?

Thank you!

Comment: In the non-simplified version, one can now see how "complicated" love has always been, or as perceived by the ancient Chinese, though one could argue that "ancient love" is very different from "modern love", as represented by the two versions here?

Comment: Your mother is correct on the left, the right could be the simplified (簡體字) 愛, or "鬼劃符" :)

Answer (score 1):

It’s the cursive form of 愛。google ：草书 爱 怎么写。 you get all possible cursive forms.